# Community bot comments might be misunderstood

Tags: discussion, community

There have lately started appearing comments on posts such as:

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. –
> Community Bot

I am curious about how these are generated and who is behind them.

I remark that I have seen posters being unsure whether this "bot" should be
taken seriously, and also, because of the very general wording, unsure of what needs
to be fixed in the post.

Are these "bot" comments really useful?

Comment: [Resolving Community user and "share feedback" issues in review queues - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369272/resolving-community-user-and-share-feedback-issues-in-review-queues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I am curious about how these are generated and who is behind them.

> Reviewers are encouraged to leave comments for the post-author, but now they can also choose from a few options of canned feedback which will appear as a comment from the Community account.

This happens when a reviewer in the "First posts → First questions AND First answers queue" chooses one of the canned options.

Example:

> [image]

Choosing one of these options posts the comment anonymously and it appears to come from the community bot.

If the use wishes to leave a comment with his own name attached they can use the standard comment link.

Source: [Review queue workflows - Final release - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release)

---

#### Are these "bot" comments really useful?

There has been feedback provided on this new feature. See [Resolving Community user and "share feedback" issues in review queues - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369272/resolving-community-user-and-share-feedback-issues-in-review-queues)

Comment: I should have searched for the info on SE Meta rather than on SU Meta. One user also asked some [pertinent questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369717/148982) that I share. I'll keep on watching that post, thank you for the information.